# Falcon & Oozie - How to configure job.properties for oozie in falcon

Tags: properties, workflow, config, oozie, falcon

I have a oozie workflow which calls a sqoop and hive action. This individual workflow works fine when I run oozie from command line.
Since the sqoop and hive scripts vary, I pass the values to the workflow.xml using job.properties file.

sudo oozie job -oozie http://hostname:port/oozie -config job.properties -run

Now I want to configure this oozie workflow in Falcon. Can you please help me in figuring out where can I configure or pass the job.properties?

Below is the falcon process.xml

```
<process name="demoProcess" xmlns="uri:falcon:process:0.1">
<tags>pipeline=degIngestDataPipeline,owner=hadoop, externalSystem=svServers</tags>
<clusters>
    <cluster name="demoCluster">
        <validity start="2015-01-30T00:00Z" end="2016-02-28T00:00Z"/>
    </cluster>
</clusters>
<parallel>1</parallel>
<order>FIFO</order>
<frequency>hours(1)</frequency>
<outputs>
    <output name="output" feed="demoFeed" instance="now(0,0)" />
</outputs>

<workflow name="dev-wf" version="0.2.07"
engine="oozie" path="/apps/demo/workflow.xml" />

<retry policy="periodic" delay="minutes(15)" attempts="3" />
</process>
```

I could not find much help on the web or the falcon documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on some development in falcon but did not try falcon vanilla a lot, but from what I understand from the tutorial below:

http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/defining-processing-data-end-end-data-pipeline-apache-falcon/

I would try creating the oozie-workflow.xml which accepts the job.properties dynamically. Place the properties file in the respective HDFS folder where workflow.xml picks it from and you can change it for every process. Now you can use your falcon process.xml and call it from command line using:

falcon entity -type process -submit -file process.xml

Also in path=/apps/demo/workflow.xml you need not specify the workflow.xml explicitly. You can just give the folder name, example:

```
<process name="rawEmailIngestProcess" xmlns="uri:falcon:process:0.1">

<tags>pipeline=churnAnalysisDataPipeline,owner=ETLGroup,externalSystem=USWestEmailServers</tags>


<clusters>
    <cluster name="primaryCluster">
        <validity start="2014-02-28T00:00Z" end="2016-03-31T00:00Z"/>
    </cluster>
</clusters>

<parallel>1</parallel>
<order>FIFO</order>
<frequency>hours(1)</frequency>

<outputs>
    <output name="output" feed="rawEmailFeed" instance="now(0,0)" />
</outputs>

<workflow name="emailIngestWorkflow" version="2.0.0"
engine="oozie" path="/user/ambari-qa/falcon/demo/apps/ingest/fs" />

<retry policy="periodic" delay="minutes(15)" attempts="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

On a second thought I felt like you can create a oozie with shell action to call sqoop_hive.sh which has the following line of code in it:

sudo oozie job -oozie http://hostname:port/oozie -config job.properties -run.

Workflow.xml looks like:

```
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="shell-wf">
<start to="shell-node"/>
<action name="shell-node">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>sqoop_hive.sh</exec>
        <argument>${feedInstancePaths}</argument>
        <file>${wf:appPath()}/sqoop_hive.sh#sqoop_hive.sh</file>
        <!-- <file>/tmp/ingest.sh#ingest.sh</file> -->
        <!-- <capture-output/> -->
    </shell>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Shell action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

Call this using falcon process call like:

falcon entity -type process -submit -file process.xml. job.properties can be changed locally if you create a shell action in oozie which calls the oozie in command line within the shell script.